# Is there a way to do load balancing in a foreach loop on windows system

Tags: r, windows, foreach, parallel-processing, load-balancing

I am running a foreach loop that does some costly computations--takes about 24 hrs. What I noted is that after 21 hours the cpu usage drops from 100% to 50% with about 50% cores/threads still running while 50% are complete, which suggests that load balancing is not correctly taking place. I know how this can be fixed in linux but have no clue with a windows system. I am using the Snow package along with foreach in **R**. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many solutions including using tasks and work stealing but this is hard to tell which one fits your need without more context... Please precise at least the programming language used. If you are dealing with black-box programs, then the question is out-of-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry for not more detailed. I am using R.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[doFuture](https://cran.r-project.org/package=doFuture)** adaptor, which gives you options to control the amount of "chunking". See Section 'Load balancing ("chunking")' in [`help("doFuture", package = "doFuture")`](https://dofuture.futureverse.org/reference/doFuture.html#load-balancing-chunking-) for details.

Comment: Thank you so much @HenrikB . I updated the script with doFuture but it did not make a difference. When I set the chunk.size = 1.0, I get what I used to get with The Snow package. If I set chunk.size = 2.0, the CPU usage decreases to 97% right at the beginning and falls to ~50 near the end before the remaining 50% clusters finish running.  Increasing chunk.size to greater than 2 further decreases the cpu usage.

Comment: DoFutures' "plan(multisession)" option could not work at all as it fails running the " xx.exe" executable file that I want to run on each cluster. Instead, the "plan(cluster, workers =100) option worked although "chunking" did not improve the previous condition.

Comment: If so (`chunk.size=1L`), it sounds like you have iterations ("tasks") that take much longer than the other iterations.  There's nothing you can do than wait for those to finish as well.

Comment: Yes, I have tasks within the foreach loop. The main task is running the same executable file within each folder (each folder is linked to a cluster). The runtime for the executable is exactly the same (the same time step and the same number of days simulated) and should finish at the same time. I am running the executable with run() function from the processx package, which masked doFuture's run() function. Can that be an issue? Thank you for the help.

Comment: `y <- foreach(..., .options.future = list(chunk.size = 1L)) %dopar% { ... }` with `registerDoFuture()`, will process _each_ iteration in a separate future. If you already use `chunk.size = 1L`, and each iteration takes the same time, then they should all finish at the same time.  Now, say you have 4 parallel workers, and 10 tasks ("iterations"), then you'll see 100% CPU load for the first eight tasks, and 50% for the last two. Could that be it? (I don't think using 'processx' in your tasks makes a difference, and, masking `run()` is ok)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had fewer tasks than the workers which led to suboptimal cpu performance. As soon as I fixed that the script using the doSNOW run at 100% cpu and runtime decreased by 4 hours. But I am unable to fully transition to doFuture. Is the syntax for linking the folders where I am running the x.exe file with workers is different for doFuture compared to Snow? I replaced everything referring to Snow with Future's in my script but I am getting this error: structure(list(args = (1:n_folder)(.doRNG.stream = list(c(10407L, -296134056L, -1048850311L, 171251174L, -1925961....

Comment: I need to see your code to comment on that, specifically your **doSNOW** setup and your `foreach()` calls. There's nothing to go by right now. So, please (always) try as far as you can to "help the helper help you".

Comment: Thank you so much again. my code is too long to paste it here. But, here is its summary: I created a table with two column which pairs process ID (Sys.getpid()) and list of folders where a program is executed.